# Detect event trigger device

Tags: c#, windows, forms, events

I have the following problem:
I wrote an Windows Forms application which contains buttons.
This runs on two mirrored screens (flat panels) that are operated by touch. Now I have to find a way to detect on which monitor a button is pressed?

I already checked the buttons event on al properties. There is a sender ID, but it depent on the button control, not the device.

Maybe someone had already solved this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to look into using low-level windows hooks (eg see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) in order to get information on which device generated the event.

Comment: This application is working well, but because of the mirrored screens the cursor position is the same on both screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solution. Because the two touch panels are connected via USB, I can determine their input trough RawInput. Here I can read the the VID (vendor ID, known from windows device manager) to distinguish them.

I got my solutions from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/caf27c51-f852-4cae-b48c-20c133a35c1a/registering-a-touch-screen-hid-with-registerrawinputdevices-does-not-work?forum=surfaceappdevelopment) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/6f8bb366-d0b4-40a9-8004-367f186cd639/using-raw-input-from-c-to-handle-multiple-mouses).